# How to frame query for this?

Tags: sql, oracle

am having query like this

```
select distinct
tran_date,
ZONE_NAME,                  
ROUND (nvl(sum(WALKIN_WITHOUT_CGROUP),0)/ COUNT(*),2)APC,
ROUND((nvl(SUM(SALES_VALUE),0)+nvl(sum(total_sales),0)-nvl(sum(net_sales),0)+nvl(sum(discount),0))/nvl(sum(BILLS_WITHOUT_CGROUP),0))ASPB,
from OUTLET_PAYMODE_REPORT_FACT A,OUTLET_DETAILS B
WHERE A.OUTLET_ID=B.OUTLET_ID and SALES_VALUE>0
group by zone_name,tran_date
```

my question is am having a date field like **tran_date with format===dd-mmm-yyyy** from this i have to seperate a column value  by date field like which i have mention below

for example:

```
  2012-AUG       ||2013-AUG || 2013-JULY

previous year|| current month || last month

    100       || 200           || 150
    120       || 300           || 500
    etc...
    etc...
```

How to separate column  and frame query for this ?

Comment: is it mysql or sqlserver ??

Comment: @shaikibrahim OP has tagged the question as Oracle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `tran_date` is what you want to pivot and it really is a date, you can do:

```
select zone_name,
       sum(case when tran_date between trunc(add_months(sysdate, -12), 'month') and
                                       trunc(add_months(sysdate, -11), 'month')
                then APC
           end) as PrevYear,
       sum(case when tran_date between trunc(add_months(sysdate, 0), 'month') and
                                       trunc(add_months(sysdate, 0), 'month')
                then APC
           end) as CurerntMonth,
       sum(case when tran_date between trunc(add_months(sysdate, -1), 'month') and
                                       trunc(add_months(sysdate, -1), 'month')
                then APC
           end) as LastMonth
from (select tran_date, ZONE_NAME,
             ROUND (nvl(sum(WALKIN_WITHOUT_CGROUP),0)/ COUNT(*),2) as APC,
             ROUND((nvl(SUM(SALES_VALUE),0)+nvl(sum(total_sales),0)- 
                    nvl(sum(net_sales),0)+nvl(sum(discount),0))/nvl(sum(BILLS_WITHOUT_CGROUP),0)
                  ) as ASPB
      from OUTLET_PAYMODE_REPORT_FACT A join
           OUTLET_DETAILS B
           on A.OUTLET_ID=B.OUTLET_ID 
      where SALES_VALUE>0
      group by zone_name,tran_date
     ) t
group by ZONE_NAME;
```

If the date is really in a string format, convert it to a date, and then follow the same method.

Comment: is there any other way can do this..?